# SQL Server 2012 Simple Recovery Model with LOG_BACKUP log_reuse_wait_desc

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, transaction-log, recovery-model

While I'm doing my own investigation, does anyone know why a database in `SIMPLE` recovery model has `LOG_BACKUP` for the `log_reuse_wait_desc`?

SQL Server 2012 SP1. Database created just a few weeks ago. No replication, no mirroring, no log shipping, and never has had any of those.

We did backup the database and restore to another instance, it shows `SIMPLE` and `NOTHING` in `log_reuse_wait` on the other instance. But I don't think restore to another instance is a good way to reproduce the problem as restore operation rolls-forward/rolls back transactions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alright, spent yesterday day and night investigating, testing and trying to reproduce the problem. Found the root cause:

`MODEL` database set to the `SIMPLE` recovery model.

If the model database has been set to the `SIMPLE` recovery model, and user databases are created with `SIMPLE` recovery model, SQL Server somehow is treating it as if it is in the `FULL` recovery model. Hence waiting for `LOG_BACKUP` to truncate the log.

I have listed the steps in this [link](http://www.travisgan.com/2013/05/sql-server-2012-simple-recovery-model.html) to show how I reproduced the problem.

I think the root cause is if a user database was created (not alter after) with simple recovery model, then it has this problem. I blame it on model database as that is the only way to create a user database with the defined recovery model.

This documented in Microsoft Knowledge Base article 2830400 and is fixed in SQL Server 2012 SP1 CU4 and RTM CU7:

- [FIX: Database does not follow simple recovery model behavior in SQL Server 2012 after you set the recovery model of the "model" database to "Simple"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2830400)