# LOG_BACKUP wait type for Transaction log file of a simple recovery model database

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

A few minutes ago I ran into a strange situation with my prod database. I have db X with simple recovery model. SCOM gave me an alert that the log disk is running out of space. I then checked the disk and saw that db X's log file is 11 Gb even though the data file is 300 Mb and the recovery model is simple.

Then I checked **DBCC OPENTRAN** but there were no open transactions, neither on the database nor on the server.

Then I tried to shrink the log file, but it said that there was no empty space.
I checked the *log_reuse_wait_type* column and it was *LOG_BACKUP*. I know that, by definition, it should be impossible to see that wait type for a database using the SIMPLE recovery model, but there it was. I double checked all the steps that I mentioned above and nothing changed. Then I changed the recovery model of db X to FULL and set it back to SIMPLE. After that *log_reuse_wait_type* reported as *NOTHING*.

In the end I solved the problem but still wonder why it happened. Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you running SQL Server 2012?  Is your model database in SIMPLE recovery model?  Are you a bit behind with your patching?

This appears to have been the issue for a previous ask of this question, at [SQL Server 2012 Simple Recovery Model with LOG_BACKUP log_reuse_wait_desc](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42068/sql-server-2012-simple-recovery-model-with-log-backup-log-reuse-wait-desc)

Fixed in [KB2830400](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2830400)  which forms part of [SQL Server 2012 CU7](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2823247) / [SQL Server 2012 SP1 CU 4](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2833645)